# How to get the short display name from a language and region code?

Tags: ios, localization

When I use `displayNameForKey`, for some language, the returned string is too long and different from the native language settings in iOS Settings app. For example:

```
let locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "zh-Hant")
let key = NSLocaleIdentifier
print(locale.displayNameForKey(key, value: "zh-Hans")!, locale.displayNameForKey(key, value: "zh-Hant-HK")!)
// return 中文（簡體）and 中文（繁體，中華人民共和國香港特別行政區）
// but what I want is like the native language settings: 簡體中文 and 繁體中文（香港）
```

How can I get the short language name?

Answer (score 0):

In iOS10, now you can use localizedString(forLanguageCode:) method of NSLocale to get the short language name.

In Swift 3

```
    let langName = NSLocale.preferredLanguages[0]
    let locale =  NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "zh-Hant")
    let fullName = locale.localizedString(forLanguageCode: lang)!
```

Comment: But the result is still not enough. For "zh-Hans" and "zh-Hant-HK", it simply returns "中文"(Chinese).